# In excel 2010/2013, using the text(value, format) formula, How do I reference another cell for the "Format_text" field?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

[image]

> Cell A1: today's date
>   Cell A3: ="Today is "&TEXT(A1, "mmm-yy")

However, I would want the "mmm-yy" to be in another cell, so I can toggle the format externally.

> Cell A4: ="Today is "&TEXT(A1, A2)

This doesn't work and I get "Today is mmm-yy" instead. How can I allow an external reference to be the format_text of the Text(value, format_text) function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In A2 remove the ""

A2 should contain mmm-yy, not "mmm-yy"